# How to use helper function in model Ruby on Rails 3.2.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my model I'm using some function

```
def normalize_account
    self.bacc = bacc.gsub(/[^0-9]/, "") if attribute_present?("bacc")
end
```

I would like to use it in different model, so it would be a good idea to put this function to the application_helper and then call this function in model? 
If yes can anyone please explain to me how to do it?

I try tu put in my helper

```
 def normalize_account (accountnum)
  self.accountnum = accountnum.gsub(/[^0-9]/, "") if attribute_present?("accountnum")
end
```

But then how to call it in model?

```
before_validation :normalize_account
```

Does't work probably need attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use ApplicationHelper for this - it is rather reserved for a methods to be used in view. What you want is to create a module and include it into models which need those method:

```
module Normalizer
  module ClassMethods
    def normalize_number(attribute)
      before_validation do
        self[attribute].gsub!(/[^0-9]/, "") unless self[attribute].nil?
      end
    end
  end

  def self.included(mod)
    mod.extend ClassMethods
  end
end

class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Normalizer
  normalize_number :accountnum
end

class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Normalizer
  normalize_number :bacc
end
```

File with your module needs to be placed somewhere in your load paths.